# How do I layout HTML Neatly

Tags: asp.net, html, css, webforms, css-position

I don't do too much HTML. But I am in need to laying out a form in a precise way almost like WinForms. Anyway here is my best attempt using the little CSS and HTML I know :

[image]

Problem is, everything inside the white area is ABSOLUTELY LAID OUT ... so everytime I add new content I have to tweak all surrounding elements to play along. Also as I am  filling the checkboxlist contents from ASP.NET code-behind I do not always know how many items there will be, so the white box sometimes is too short... so I fix this by MANUALLY fixing the new height in CSS... bad way as you know.

Please can you tell me how I *SHOULD* be doing this?

CSS :

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #111;
    background: #c4c4c4 url("bgd.jpg");
}

#header
{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#wrapper
{
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    height: auto;
}

#footer
{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#copyright
{
    font-size: smaller;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.block
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 440px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
}

.block > *
{
    position: relative;
}

#login
{
    width: 215px;
    height: 170px;
}

#login h2
{
    background: #353;
}

#controlpanel
{
    width: 235px;
    height: 175px;
}

#controlpanel h2
{
    background: rgb(165,0,0);
}

#options
{
    width: 273px;
    height:auto;
}

#options h2
{
    background: royalblue;
}

.block h2
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    background: #261F1F;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

h1, h2, h3
{
    color: #111111;
    margin: 0px;
}

h1
{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 22px;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
}

a
{
    -moz-outline: none;
}

hr
{
    background: #dddddd;
    color: #dddddd;
}

.button
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 27px;
    color: #111111;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: url('btnbgd.png') top;
    border: 1px solid #C3C4BA;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.textbox
{
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.label
{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #eee;
}

select 
{
    border: 1px solid #C3C4BA;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 25px;
}

.groupbox
{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #eee;
    left: 12px;
    width: 250px;
}

fieldset 
{
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.groupbox legend
{
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #C3C4BA; 
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#MainContentPlaceHolder_pnlXRefs legend
{
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red; 
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.footer
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #575654;
}
```

HTML :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Options.aspx.cs" Inherits="Portal.Options"
    MasterPageFile="Portal.Master" Title="Price File Options" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder">
    <div class="block" id="options">
        <h2>
            Options</h2>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Acc No :" Style="top: 15px; left: 15px;" CssClass="label" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccNo" runat="server" Style="top: 15px; left: 15px; width: 110px"
            CssClass="textbox" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetColours" Style="top: 15px; left: 15px" CssClass="button" runat="server"
            Text="Refresh" onclick="btnGetColours_Click" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlBrembo" runat="server" GroupingText="BREMBO" Style="top: 25px;"
            CssClass="groupbox">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="lstBrembo" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>



        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Email :" Style="top: 85px; left: 15px;" CssClass="label" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Style="top: 85px; left: 24px; width: 185px"
            Text="a@b.com" CssClass="textbox" />

        </br>
        <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" Style="top: 100px; left: 12px" CssClass="button" runat="server"
            Text="Generate & Send" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After taking the height: 2000px; out and even changing it to auto for the whitebox I get some controls at the bottom pushed out of the white box :

[image]

Comment: Do not give your box a fixed height then.

Comment: "everything inside the white area is ABSOLUTELY LAID OUT" — Don't do that. Normal flow is what this needs.

Comment: @Quentin but how do I get the fine control using the normal flow?

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:auto` to the inner block div.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Tj5x/)**

You can check the height variation by removing/adding list items in the above demo/

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes by default display inline, (which means side by side) - you need to set `display: block;` on them explicitly.

To do this I would wrap each checkbox field in its own div, and then style that to make it display as a block.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/alexpls/Yr87Z/

And here's some information on the CSS `display` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to re design and use floats, they make it much easier to control when the amount of items on a page is not static.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SpuA/) that sort of shows what you can do. Copy and paste the `#item` div as many times as you like and the positioning should be fine